# Convert Notepad++ user defined language to html

Tags: html, notepad++, user-defined

I have created a user defined language using Notepad++. Now I want to convert this into html format. There are many free source tools available which can convert lets say rtf file to html but how can i convert this user defined language file into html?

Notepad++ allows me to save this file which is in user-defined language with any extension but the formatted text can only be viewed in notepad++.

Like if I save the file as draft.rtf, open the file in notepad++ the changes (formated text of user defined language) will stay but when I open the same file in Word the changes are lost!

A simple copy paste from notepad++ to Word also causes the text to lose its user-defined language specifications. Kindly help.

Comment: A "user-defined" language in Notepad++ is just a highlighting scheme.  There's no way to convert it to HTML.  I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @andi: It sound like he wants his custom highlighting to scheme to be converted to an HTML file so that it looks the same when opened in his web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the NppExport plugin, it will export your file with the syntax highlighted as html (i think) and then you can use that somewhere else

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/nppexport-for-notepad-export-highlighted-code-in-html-rtf-format/